# Formula for the Wythoff array from the infinite Fibonacci word

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, combinatorics-on-words, oeis

I have a question pertaining to whether the following way of writing the Wythoff array obtained from the Fibonacci sequence / infinite Fibonacci word is known or obvious.

Let $n$ be an integer.

Let $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$ denote the $n$-th Fibonacci number such that $F(0) = 0$ and $F(1) = 1$.

Let $S_{\infty}$ denote the [infinite Fibonacci word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_word) function ([A014675](https://oeis.org/A014675)) and let $N_{\infty}$ be the function that maps the occurrences of the natural numbers $\{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ to the digits of the Fibonacci word, so for instance,

$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        S_0 = 2 &: N_0 = 00  \\
        S_1 = 21 &: N_1 = 001 \\
        S_2 = 212 &: N_2 = 00122 \\
        S_3 = 21221 &: N_3 = 00122334 \\
        \vdots
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

We can treat $N_{\infty}$ as a vector such that $N_{\infty}(i)$ is the $i$-th indexed element.

For some non-negative integers $i$ and $j$, let $W(i,j)$ denote the $i,j$-th element of the [Wythoff array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wythoff_array) ([A035513](https://oeis.org/A035513))

**Question**: Is it obvious that

$$
W(i,j) = 2 F_j + \alpha F_{j+1} + \beta F_{j+2} 
$$

for all $i \geq 2$ and for all $j \geq 1$ where

$$
\alpha = - N_{\infty}(i-2)) + i - 1 \quad \text{and} \quad
\beta = N_{\infty}(i-2)
$$

Notes:

1. This might be obvious and/or I may just be writing something in a convoluted way.
2. I am a computer scientist and not a number theorist by training (see point 1, and my apologies if this is trivial).
3. I have code that verifies this pattern for several hundred rows/terms of the Wythoff sequence (see point 2) and would be happy to share it if helpful.